# Limit to infinity with natural logarithms $\lim_{x\to \infty } \left(\frac{\ln (2 x)}{\ln (x)}\right)^{\ln (x)} $

Tags: limits, logarithms

I found the following problem in my calculus book:
Solve:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } \left(\frac{\ln (2 x)}{\ln (x)}\right)^{\ln (x)} $$

I tried to solve it using log rules and l'Hôpital's rule with no success, can someone give me any hints on how to go about this?

Answer (score 15):

HINT: Using [Sum of Logarithms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms#Sum_of_Logarithms),

$$\dfrac{\ln2x}{\ln x}=1+\dfrac{\ln2}{\ln x}$$

and set $\dfrac{\ln2}{\ln x}=n$ in $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n=e$$

Finally if $a^x=M$ from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Definition), $x=\log_aM$

$$\displaystyle\implies a^{\log_aM}=M$$ (See [also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Canceling_exponentials))

Comment: @BrianJ, Do you understand the difference between your edition & my original answer?

Comment: I based it around what looked like substituting the exponent for n. So I updated the others to match. If you did more than a simple substitution, then I clearly missed it.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln x}\right)^{\ln x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln2+\ln x}{\ln x}\right)^{\ln x}= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}}\right)^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}\cdot\ln 2}=e^{\ln 2}=2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } \Big(\frac{\ln(2x)}{\ln(x)}\Big)^{\ln(x)} $$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty } \Big(\frac{\ln(x)+\ln 2}{\ln(x)}\Big)^{\ln(x)} $$ $$=\lim_{x\to \infty } \Big(1+\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(x)}\Big)^{\ln(x)} $$ $$=\lim_{x\to \infty }exp\Big(\ln(x)\Big(1+\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(x)}-1\Big)\Big) $$ $$=\lim_{x\to \infty }exp\Big(\ln (x)\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(x)}\Big)\Big) $$ $$=\lim_{x\to \infty }exp\Big(\ln 2\Big)=e^{\ln 2}=2 $$

Comment: How do you reach from third expression to fourth? I think fourth expression should be $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\exp\left\{\ln x\ln\left(1 + \frac{\ln 2}{\ln x}\right)\right\}$$

Comment: Kindly, notice $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-1\right)}=e$$

Comment: No it happens like $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}=\exp\left\{\lim_{x \to \infty}x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right\}  = \exp(1) = e$$

Comment: Yes, it's correct method. But I showed you a short cut method.

Comment: It appears that you are using the following crafty rule: if $f(x) \to 1, g(x) \to \infty$ then $\{f(x)\}^{g(x)} \to \exp\{\lim g(x)(f(x) - 1)\}$

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{\ln (2x)}{\ln x}\right)^{\ln x} $$
$$=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{\ln 2+\ln x}{\ln x}\right)^{\ln x} $$
$$=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{\ln 2}{\ln x}+1\right)^{\ln x} $$
$$=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}}+1\right)^{\ln x} $$
Let $n=\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$, then
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\ln 2} $$
$$=\left(\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^{\ln 2} $$
$$=e^{\ln 2}=2$$